# Excel Bubble Chart Transparency Based on Values

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to set the transparency of the bubble chart based on values in Excel (Office 365)? Each of the bubbles has a value that determines the size and a probability associated with the value that I want to use to manage color transparency.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?  If you record a macro while changing the transparency of a single point that will give you a start.

Answer (score 1):

The transparency is under the [`Point`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.point(object)) object, and will be the property `.Format.Fill.Transparency`.

To apply this to each `Point` you can loop the [`Points`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.points(object)) of that specific Chart.

Here is a demo using a Chart Object, but apply the logic for your specific chart.

```vb
Private Sub demoChartFormat()
    Dim point As point
    For Each point In Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points
        With point
            .Format.Fill.Transparency = 0.5 ' Number from 0 to 1
        End With
    Next point
End Sub
```

Note for future reference, I found this by searching [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/). This site is very helpful for searching through specific Objects and their properties, just use the search functionality in it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select 'Number of the series
    
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Select 'Specific point of the series. 1 represents the first row of data
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 256)
        .transparency = 0.737066979 'This is where the probability value goes, which drives transparency
        .Solid
    End With
```

[image]